# Почему выдаёт ошибку 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python

Я хочу использовать код -
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
import aiohttp
import os
import re

uri = os.getenv("DB_URL")
if uri.startswith("postgres://"):
    uri = uri.replace("postgres://", "postgresql://", 1)
    DB_URL = 'postgresql://postgres:123123@localhost:5432/parser'
```

А он мне ошибку -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sinto/PycharmProjects/OLX/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    import config
  File "C:\Users\sinto\PycharmProjects\OLX\config.py", line 6, in <module>
    if uri.startswith("postgres://"):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Comment: а что скриншотом то? за это в аду отдельный котел

Comment: Всё ок, давайте напишу сам код

import aiohttp
import os
import re

uri = os.getenv("DB_URL")
if uri.startswith("postgres://"):
    uri = uri.replace("postgres://", "postgresql://", 1)
    DB_URL = 'postgresql://postgres:123123@localhost:5432/parser'

Comment: а у вас вообще в системе есть такая сетевая переменная `DB_URL`?

Comment: Это не мой проект, а готовый. Я сейчас пытаюсь исправить ошибку, а появляется вторая и так зациклено. Я в целом не понимаю что такое сетевая переменная.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B - почитайте - это переменная у системы, которой могут пользоваться разные программы (например в таких переменных прописаны некоторые общие пути), если у вас такая переменная окружения/среды не задана, то и функция вернет NoneType как я понимаю

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Проблема в том, что у вас в переменных окружения нет переменной `DB_URL`